# How to get the padding from the edge of the UITableview to the UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, padding

On the iPad, the Grouped style tableview's cells are inset deeper from the edge of the tableview than on the iPhone.

I need to retrieve the Left and Right distances from the edges of the tableview to where the cell begins.  What i'm referring to is similar to "Margins".   I read the UITableview API up and down and can't find a property that returns this.

I need to use this in calculation to compute where to position content in my cells.

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but i'm pretty sure you should just be able to pick up the frame of both and then compare from there.

```
CGRect cellFrame = yourCell.frame;

CGRect tableFrame = yourUITableView.frame;
```

The CGRect values are `(x coordinate, y coordinate, width, height)`.

Also you can just print out the frames using :

```
 NSLog(@"your cell frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(yourCell.frame);
 NSLog(@"your table frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(yourUITableView.frame);
```

Comment: The thing is:  until tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: is called, the frame will contain wrong values.  At the time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, the cells are not scaled up yet to the screen size.   So if you do cell.frame.width on an ipad, in cellForRowAtIndexPath with an iPhone storyboard, you will get 320. And it should be 750+    But if you do cell.frame.width in willDisplayCell, you will get the correct value.  The problem is, it's too late at that point.  I need to have the margins earlier.

Comment: One workaround i found so far is: to first detect if the device is an IPad.  If it is, i add 40 points as approxiate padding in my calculation.  Definitely not a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with overriding the layoutSubviews call for the iPad and setting the grouped view margins to what I want them to be, rather then what the apparently hidden value is. Other answers in Stack point out that it can vary from 10 to 45 pixels in width.

```
In your CustomTableViewCell class
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect f = self.bounds;
    f = CGRectInset(f, 10, 0);
    self.contentView.frame = f;
    self.backgroundView.frame = f;
}
```

You could force it to keep contentView and backgroundView to be equal to that of the TableCell width which is that TableView width, but in this case I still wanted my grouped view to be inset a little bit. It also allows you to better match with a custom header/footer view which will go edge to edge without work.